# How to deal with application (Java) that listen random port (using erlang otp protocol) in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Java application that create thread on demand. Each thread listen a specific port. The application assign a random port choosen from an available tcp port to the thread when creating it.

So basically, when I want to communicate with this application, I send a message on a fixed port, the application answer me the port on which I'll be able to communicate with and then start the conversation.

This workflow rely on the Erlang/OTP protocol using this Java package : http://erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/java/index.html

I have put my application on a Docker container and know wants to create a Kubernetes service to make this application callable from other pods.

Problem is : since the port I'm able to communicate with the application is not fixed, I cannot simply configure a Kubernetes service using the classic `spec.ports`.

Is there a way, in Kubernetes, to declare a service that map an entire virtual IP (all port opened)?

Comment: I recognize this isn't what you asked, but it sounds like that setup is trying to recreate TCP in reverse; connections to a well-known port (e.g. `:80`) do not exclusively block `:80` and force next connections to wait until the first connection is finished; [a pseudo-example](https://pastebin.com/AT63nzN6) shows a pretty common pattern. Is there something about Erlang/OTP that mandates the situation you describe?

Comment: Separately, I don't have a cluster in front of me to test, but each Pod in k8s gets a unique IP (in most(?) setups, anyway) so I would guess that as long as k8s doesn't _forbid_ such a thing, `pod-a` can talk without restriction to `pod-b`'s IP; the `Service` is merely an abstraction away from discussing specific Pods in config, injections, etc